# Problem with show/hide snackbar on slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a type of slideshow that shows small messages moving forward and backward on each slide. The slide forward button works normally with the fade-out effect, but when I try to add a return button, the effect does not work.

How should I do this?

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab")
var index = 0;



const slide = (i) => {

  tabs.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = "none";       
  })

  index = index + i;
  tabs[index].style.display = "block";
}

slide(0); 



document.querySelectorAll(".next").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {

      item.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('out')

       setTimeout(function() {
        slide(1)
       }, 600);

  })    
})

document.querySelectorAll(".prev").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {

      item.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('out')

       setTimeout(function() {
        slide(-1)
       }, 600);

  })    
})
```

```css
.tab {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}

.bottom-sack-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.snackbar {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation-name: example;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="background: gold">

 <h1>Slide 1 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>



<div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 2 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">Prev</button>
          <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 3 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">Prev</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The snackbar disappears when I click the back button, when the same effect should be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is whenever you call `slide`, you are adding the `.out` CSS class to the current snackbar but never removing it, so whenever you clicked Prev, it went back and that previous snackbar still had `.out`.

To get it working, I added a another `classList.toggle("out")` in your timeout after the `slide()` so it will remove the `.out` once you are on the next/previous slide.

Since it was now called a few times, I added a new function:

```
const toggleClass = (element, className) => {
    element.classList.toggle(className);
}
```

So then I could do:

```
const snackbar = item.parentElement.parentElement;
toggleClass(snackbar, "out");
```

and then also call `toggleClass(snackbar, "out");` in the `setTimeout`.

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
var index = 0;

const slide = (i) => {
  tabs.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.display = "none";
  });

  index = index + i;
  tabs[index].style.display = "block";
};

const toggleClass = (element, className) => {
  element.classList.toggle(className);
}

slide(0);

document.querySelectorAll(".next").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const snackbar = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    toggleClass(snackbar, "out");

    setTimeout(function () {
      slide(1);
      toggleClass(snackbar, "out");
    }, 600);
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll(".prev").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const snackbar = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    toggleClass(snackbar, "out");

    setTimeout(function () {
      slide(-1);
      toggleClass(snackbar, "out");
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}

.bottom-sack-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.snackbar {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation-name: example;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 1 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">
      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Slide 1 Snack</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="next">
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 2 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">
      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">
          Slide 2 Snack
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">
            Prev
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="next">
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 3 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">
      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">
          Slide 3 Snack
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">
            Prev
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all the `.out` before toggle it:

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab")
var index = 0;



const slide = (i) => {

  tabs.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = "none";       
  })

  index = index + i;
  tabs[index].style.display = "block";
}

slide(0); 



document.querySelectorAll(".next").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".snackbar");
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("out");
});
      item.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('out')

       setTimeout(function() {
        slide(1)
       }, 600);

  })    
})


document.querySelectorAll(".prev").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".snackbar");
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("out");
});
      item.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('out')

       setTimeout(function() {
        slide(-1)
       }, 600);

  })    
})
```

```css
.tab {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}

.bottom-sack-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.snackbar {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation-name: example;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="background: gold">

 <h1>Slide 1 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>



<div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 2 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">Prev</button>
          <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="tab" style="background: gold">
    <h1>Slide 3 </h1>
    <div class="bottom-sack-container">

      <div class="snackbar">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi nisi iste voluptates sed ea a</div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="button" class="prev">Prev</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```